# WSO2 API Publish Endpoints

Tags: java, api, wso2, restful-url

I am a greenhorn to WSO2 and run into a problem when implementing Restful Endpoints in publisher.

The production and sandbox endpoints cannot pass testing with 404 error not found. However, the restful service is successful in Postman and also can be invoked in other Apps,

New API steps,

[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsSrm.png)

[Implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSD5p.png)

Thanks for any points.

Comment: what is the API Manager version are you used?

Comment: This is definitely because you have not defined the resource properly or not provided the correct backend url. If you can update your question with the restful resource you want to invoke and the backend service url, I could be able to help.

Comment: Thanks guys, I changed to use Address Endpoint instead of HTTP Endpoint and it works.